# How do add degree of separation?

Tags: prolog

In Prolog, how would I make a rule that checks how many people come in one persons network and then query it on degree of separation?

For example, if in Facebook my name is John; and I have one friend Tom, and Tom has one friend Lucy, and Lucy has one friend Ben, and Ben has one friend Josh, and Josh has one friend Nancy.

I want to create a rule in Prolog that tests how many people are in my network and also tell Prolog to return names up to a given number of degree of separation.

e.g. if I query something like;

```
?- mynetwork(josh,2).
```

Prolog should return

- John
- Tom
- Lucy

or

- John is friends with Tom
- Tom is friends with Lucy

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Prolog!

First you're going to need some facts:

```
friend(john, tom).
friend(tom, lucy).
friend(lucy, ben).
...
```

For simplicity, let's consider the case where friendships are directed: I can friend you, but that doesn't mean you friend me.

Let's say we're friends of degree 1 if I have friended you. That would look like this:

```
network(Person, 1, Friend) :- friend(Person, Friend).
```

Now the inductive case is one in which we've found a friend through a friend. That's going to look like this:

```
network(Person, N1, FoaF) :-
  N1 > 1, 
  N0 is N1-1,
  network(Person, N0, Friend),
  network(Friend, 1, FoaF).
```

Using `is/2` you can be sure the predicate will be ill-behaved. For instance, if you omit the `> 1` constraint, you will be able to ask questions and get N back that you won't if you include it. But you'll also get errors about being out of local stack. So if you can afford to, bring in `clpfd` now:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

network(Person, 1, Friend) :- friend(Person, Friend).
network(Person, N1, FoaF) :-
  N1 #> 0,
  N0 #= N1-1,
  network(Person, N0, Friend),
  network(Friend, 1, FoaF).
```

This should work for all input cases you care to try, though it still has no way to know when you're out of friendship levels.

```
?- network(john, N, X).
N = 1,
X = tom ;
N = 2,
X = lucy ;
N = 3,
X = ben ;
^CAction (h for help) ? abort
% Execution Aborted

?- network(john, 3, X).
X = ben ;
false.

?- network(john, 2, X).
X = lucy ;
false.
```

**Edit** Let me answer your questions out of order.

> Where is the print statement?

By design, I haven't used one. Until here, we're just using the Prolog REPL (read-eval-print loop) to do our I/O. This is the natural way to work with Prolog. You'll save yourself a lot of heartache later if you go to some trouble to separate predicates that do I/O and user presentation from predicates concerned with meaning. This is just a petite application of model-view separation. You also benefit from keeping side-effects quarantined in their own predicates. As long as the pure logical part of your program is self-contained, you will always be able to build and compose with it.

> How would you print upto a given number of people. e.g. if you type in network(john, 3, X). then it should print out upto N=3 X=ben

I would be inclined to call this predicate `show_network/2` instead and keep the separation going. You could do it on the cheap with a failure-driven loop like so:

```
show_network(Person, Max) :-
  between(1, Max, N),
  network(Person, N, Friend),
  format('~w is friends with ~w\n', [Person, Friend]),
  fail.
show_network(_, _).
```

This will work like so:

```
?- show_network(john, 3).
john is friends with tom.
john is friends with lucy.
john is friends with ben.
true.
```

There are other approaches too, for instance, you could use `forall/2`:

```
show_network(Person, Max) :-
   forall(
     (between(1, Max, N), network(Person, N, Friend)),
     format('~w is friends with ~w\n', [Person, Friend])).
```

The relationship between the failure-driven loop and that one should be pretty clear. You could also manually get the list and then process it with `maplist/2` or something:

```
show_network(Person, Max) :-
  findall(friend(Person,Friend), 
          (between(1, Max, N), network(Person, N, Friend)), 
          Friends),
  maplist(show_friend, Friends).

show_friend(friend(Person, Friend)) :-
  format('~w is friends with ~w\n', [Person, Friend]).
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very detailed and very helpful. I have few questions, how would you print upto a given number of people. e.g. if you type in network(john, 3, X). then it should print out upto N=3 X=ben, from the example you gave above. and also what does FoaF, N0, use_module(library(clpfd)) mean?. btw once again thanks this is very detailed.

Comment: Also where is the print statement?

Comment: I have added some discussion of your questions to the answer, please take a look.

Comment: @mat Good call, will fix.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Could you please explain to me what does FoaF mean? and also suddenly the rule stopped working, instead of printing N = 1,
X = tom ;
N = 2,
X = lucy ;
N = 3,
X = ben ;, it replaces N with 1 and not 1, 2, 3.... any idea why? and also would it be possible to make the code any smaller?

Comment: Hi, also would it possible to print the result in a list? e.g. ([ben,tom,lucy,...,...,...]).

Comment: FoaF = friend of a friend. The rule didn't suddenly stop working, it is exactly what I meant when I said "it has no way to know when you run out of friendship levels." Not sure what the rest of your question there means. It is not likely to be possible to make the code substantially smaller. Prolog is not known for being terse. If you want the results in a list, use `findall/3` or `setof/3` on `network/3` and print them with a new predicate.